# zip only the last directory in the path

Tags: zip

To backup my document root (`/var/www/html/` I can execute):

```
zip -r ~/backups/all_zipped-$(date +\%F-\%T).zip /var/www/html/
```

The problem is that **inside** the created zip file, I get 3 base directories instead of 1:

1. `var`.
2. `www`.
3. `html`.

The desired end state is to have only 1 base directory (the last one). In this case, of course, `html` (and its inodes).

Using `zip -r ~/backups/all_zipped-$(date +\%F-\%T).zip /var/www/html/*` (note the `*`), didn't help.

How to zip current directory without its entire path?

Comment: is there any particular reason why you're using zip rather than tar? do you need to share the backups with windows systems?

Comment: Comfortability. Indeed, it's shared with Windows systems, there it's extracted by WinRAR.

Comment: Add output of `unzip -l ~/backups/all_zipped-$(date +\%F-\%T).zip` to your question. If necessary, reduce the number of lines to the important lines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, `zip` stores relative paths, not absolute ones, so if you perform the `zip` operation from the `/var/www` directory, you should get what you want. In the one-liner below, `cd -` returns you to whatever directory you were in before.

```
cd /var/www && zip -r ~/backups/all_zipped-$(date +\%F-\%T).zip html/ && cd -
```

Comment: I don't see how my edit https://unix.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/228048 does not improve the post even a little bit. Downvoting for the poor formatting you chose to retain.

Comment: Current formatting is fine and your formatting didn't improve anything.

Comment: @xenoid OP used GitHub-style triple-backtick formatting. That's not a proper code block in Stack Exchange Markdown. See how Cyrus's edit has changed. That's exactly what I tried to do. Please read https://unix.stackexchange.com/editing-help/#code and familiarize yourself with the formatting here.